# Pig script error with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My Pig-script won't run as I am getting this error message:

```
ls: cannot access /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1415547956892_0004/container_1415547956892_0004_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/lib/slf4j-api-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1415547956892_0004/container_1415547956892_0004_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/lib/commons-lang3-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1415547956892_0004/container_1415547956892_0004_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/hcatalog/lib/*hbase-storage-handler-*.jar: No such file or directory
Error: Could not find or load main class hive.metastore.sasl.enabled=false
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly to do?

Any help would be appreciated as I'm dealing with this all day.

Comment: It seems you may have a misconfiguration in hue. Try running pig from the command line if you need a quick workaround.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? Please bear with me that I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

do this,

1) COPY THESE FILES TO THE HADOOP LIBRARY.

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.7.0-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/ 
sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
```

2)CLOSE HBASE AND HADOOP USING FOLLOWING COMMOND

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
/usr/lib/hbase/bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

3) RESTART HBASE AND HADOOP USING COMMOND

```
 /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Now create table in hive using Hbase storage handler.

in hive-site.xml write this property

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but when I run the first line I get the message: cp: cannot stat '/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.7.0-cdh3u0.jar'. By the way, should I run the commands directly after: [root@sandbox ~]# ?

Comment: what are you doing man, in command hive path is according to my system. I am using Apache hive. give your hive lib path.

Comment: Im really quite clueless about this, can you please show me how to do it through teamviewer so you can see how my hadoop is configured? I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: what are you using cloudera, mapr or opensource apache hive??

Comment: I am using HortonWorks Sandbox VM, and via a server I get to the hadoop interface with the components where I write the pig script

Comment: I am confused, you are using pig and error is belongs to hive and hbase jar.